# Cordova display website in in-app browser

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Cordova, and am trying to build an Android app.

I have the sample code working, and have run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and modified the `www/index.html` file to add the following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
function onDeviceReady()
{
        // Now safe to use the Codova API
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
        var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

But all I see when I call `cordova emulate android` is the Cordova logo in the app.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you included `cordova.js` ?

Comment: Any errors in logs?

Comment: Have you replace your files into `www` folder and then build it ?

Comment: Yes, cordova.js is included (as I just modified the sample index.html).

Comment: The index.html is in the www folder.  I run 'cordova emulate android' to build it & see it in the emulator